# Exclude property from form binding in .NET 8 Minimal API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

In order to avoid using `Tuple<,>` and reduce the amount of types used when passing input models and optional validation errors I have included the `List<ValidationFailure>` from `FluentValidation` as a property in the input model.

When rendering the response using a Razor template the validation failures are used to add error classes and explicit errors to the form.

Processing a POST request fails because the handler tries to bind the property with `List<ValidationFailure>` from the data posted.

Is there a way to exclude the property from form binding?

The usual attributes `[BindNever]` and `[JsonIgnore]` have no effect in this case.

Example code:

The input model:

```cs
public class CreateToDoModel
{
    // Should be bound
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // Should be bound
    public string Due { get; set; }
    // Should NOT be bound
    public List<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure>? Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Handler:

```cs
app.MapPost($"/todos", async (IMediator mediator, [FromForm] CreateToDoModel model, IValidator<CreateToDoModel> validator, IHttpContextAccessor context) =>
{
    model.Errors = (await validator.ValidateAsync(model)).Errors;

    // Any validation errors? If so, re-render the view.
    if (model.Errors.Count !=0 ) return Results.Extensions.RazorSlice($"{TemplatePath}Create.cshtml", model);

    // Validation ok - send command
    var result = await mediator.Send(new CreateToDoCommand { Description = model.Description, Due = DateOnly.Parse(model.Due) });

    // (Error handling excluded)
}
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? Ideally runnable [mre].

Comment: JFY `IHttpContextAccessor context` is not needed, you can just inject `HttpContext` in Minimal API handlers.

Comment: Can you please add sample request JSON and error you get? Also from what namespace is the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` used?

Comment: No JSON is involved here, form binding is used since the client is issuing a standard html-form POST.

The long-shot use of JsonIgnore attribute to perhaps exclude the property from binding is from System.Text.Json.Serialization.

I want to bind the strings "Description" and "Due" but not "Errors" which should be ignored by the handler.

The error is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Type 'FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure' does not have a constructor. A single public constructor is required for mapping the type."

Comment: TBH was not able to repro. I don't have any binding errors. Can you please share a full [mre] and sample request somewhere like github?

Comment: Sure, check out https://github.com/jensj/BindingDemo

Se the notes under the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore property from from binding in Minimal APIs one option would be to use [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?view=net-8.0):

```
public class CreateToDoModel
{
    // Should NOT be bound
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public List<ValidationFailure>? Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Using internal setter will work also:

```
public class CreateToDoModel
{
    // Should NOT be bound
    public List<ValidationFailure>? Errors { get; internal set; }
}
```

Minimal API vastly differs from the MVC and and as far as I understand it uses it's own set of binders which firstly are designed with goal of perfromance. If I understand it correctly - you can see how current implementation builds set of properties to bind [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints/FormMapping/Metadata/FormDataMetadataFactory.cs,186) (or [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3079a17461ddcd4c8eadb97f13675a381c806870/src/Components/Endpoints/src/FormMapping/Metadata/FormDataMetadataFactory.cs#L186)).

Comment: Excellent - Both solutions work well.